# Show that $\nabla . *F = 0$ is a geometric frame independent of ...

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, electromagnetism

Show that $\nabla\cdot\ast F = 0$ (divergence of the dual of the EMF tensor) is a geometric frame independent version of $F_{ab,c} + F_{bc,a} + F_{ca,b} = 0$, where $F$ is the electromagnetic field tensor

I don't know how to answer this question.

We know that $\ast F_{ab} = \frac12 F^{\mu \nu} \epsilon _{\mu \nu a b}$, but i am having problem to define the divergence here, i mean, if we denote $\nabla = \sum_{i=0}^3 \partial_{i}$, we will need to compute a lot of things, i mean, F already has 16 components (i am not counting the symmetries here), plus this derivatives, it will be really a problematic computation. Summarizing, i would demonstrate at first that this divergence is zero, and so demonstrate that it is invariant under Lorentz transformation, but i think this is not the best way.

So i gave up this alternative, and i would appreciate another way to solve it.

Comment: I assume you are only dealing with SR here and not GR?

Comment: I think you have sorely complicated this question. It has not asked you to prove that divergence is zero, it gives you that already. It asks you to show that the equations involving derivatives of $F$ are equivalent (mod some factor of $4!$ depending on your convention)

Comment: @user10354138 ooh yes, SR. i forgot to put it! thx